# struts2 namespace name issue

Tags: namespaces, struts2

Hi i am using struts2 and hibernate in my project. I need to use a namespace for my admin section so that i have used the namepace as `companyAdmin` and i have created a folder inside the web folder named `companyAdmin` and it is worked fine. But when i delete the folder `companyAdmin` from the web folder the struts show an error error message when trying to access the namespace. Is there a folder with name as namespace name is a must in struts2 for using the namespace. Also i can't able to use the namespace as "admin" even though i have created a folder in the web folder with a name admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be clear that Struts2 namespace is nothing related to folder/any other resource in your web-application.

Namespace inside Struts2 subdivides action configurations into ***logical modules***, each with its own identifying prefix.Namespaces avoid conflicts between action names.

This is what doc say about namespace

> Namespaces are not a path!
>   Namespace are not hierarchical like a file system path. There is one namespace level. For example if the URL /barspace/myspace/bar.action is requested, the framework will first look for namespace /barspace/myspace. If the action does not exist at /barspace/myspace, the search will immediately fall back to the default namespace "". The framework will not parse the namespace into a series of "folders". In the Namespace Example, the bar action in the default namespace would be selected.

I suggest you to go through the official documentation of Namespace to get an idea what they are and how they work inside S2

- [namespace-configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/namespace-configuration.html)

Comment: i got the idea very clear about what is name space from the link above. But the problem persist in my server is that when i am using namespace as "admin" the myserver.com/admin shows the page not found error. But if i am using namespace as "administrator" it is getting on my server. I don't know why i can't use the namespace as "admin" in my server.

Comment: Amazon cloud server. server.mydrdirect.com